# How to gather data left of a string of text in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a SQL that is used to return all customer data, however, it is all in one field. The SQL I am using is:

```
SELECT Cust_Desc
FROM All_Cust_Data
```

Cust_Desc returns the following information in the following format

```
John, Doe, Client ID 7, Region Code, 4....
```

I need to split the data left of everything from `, Region Code` so the query returns only `John, Doe, Client ID 7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `regexp_replace`

```
with All_Cust_Data(Cust_Desc) as
(
 select 'John, Doe, Client ID 7, Region Code, 4....' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(Cust_Desc,'(.*),.\Region Code.*','\1') as "Result String"
  from All_Cust_Data;

    Result String
-----------------------
John, Doe, Client ID 7
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/WTHK7402)

Answer (score 0):

Try substr and instr functions combined

```
select Cust_Desc, substr(Cust_Desc,0,INSTR(Cust_Desc,'Region Code')-1) from All_Cust_Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
SQL> with all_cust_data (cust_Desc) as
  2    (select 'John, Doe, Client ID 7, Region Code, 4....' from dual)
  3  select rtrim(trim(substr(cust_Desc, 1, instr(cust_desc, 'Region Code') - 1)), ',') result
  4  from all_cust_data;

RESULT
----------------------
John, Doe, Client ID 7

SQL>
```

It uses the old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination; `TRIM` functions are here to remove trailing spaces and comma (the one behind number `7,`)